# "Purely inseparable, algebraic extension if and only if trivial automorphism group"

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, automorphism-group, positive-characteristic

Let  $k \subset K$ be an algebraic field extension, with $\mathrm{char} \, k=p>0$. Is it true the following assertion?

$k \subset K$ is purely inseparable if and only if $\mathrm{Aut}_k(K)=\{1\}$; where $\mathrm{Aut}_k(K)$ are the automorphisms of $K$ which fix $k$. I showed the arrow $\Rightarrow$ and i think it works. What about the arrow $\Leftarrow$?.

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $K=\Bbb F_5(t)$ and $k=\Bbb F_5(t^3)$ then the extension is separable but there are no automorphisms as there are no 3rd roots of $1$ in $k$ (besides $1$).

Comment: Yes. Not normal.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think there are some hypothesis to add to get the implication requested?

Comment: @FrancescoDenisi normal extension is certainly such a hypothesis